# Popen.returncode not working in Python?

Tags: python

I have a price of code which transfers file from server to local machine. However, the directory the user enters may not be always correct. If the user enters the incorrect directory I am trying to show the error. If the `returncode` is not None I will show the error. But this doesn't work. No matter what the program throws it always go to `else` part.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess



result = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', 'password', 'rsync', '-avz', '--info=progress2', 'username@host_name:/file_name', '/home/zurelsoft/test'], 
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

if result.returncode != None:
    print "Directory Incorrect"

else:
    print "Done"
    print result
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Popen` directly instead of `check_call`?

Comment: I am using Python version 2.6.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` returns an object (result variable in your case). You need to call the `poll` or the `wait` method of this object to set the returncode status. Then you can check the `result.returncode`

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode

> The child return code, set by poll() and wait() (and indirectly by communicate()). A None value indicates that the process hasn’t terminated yet.

Comment: Actually I will need the communicate()[0] too in my code so I can't use wait() or poll() method with the subprocess Object.